# How to hide Youtube homepage and sidebar?

Tags: youtube

I want to remove Suggestions in YouTube homepage and sidebar as it is distracting. In PC, there are extensions to remove this(like "YouTube rabbit hole" and "DF YouTube"). But how to do this in YouTube mobile app?

Comment: Have you tried NewPipe? https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.schabi.newpipe/

Comment: @AbhinavPB I have fixed the link in Robert's comment. Try it again. It should load in English language. The app he mentioned can do what you want. I have set it up to not show me garbage called "Suggestions" whenever I open it. To be clear here, it is an app in itself. It doesn't change anything in your YouTube app per se.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks. But,It seems that you cannot upload videos with this app.I have a YouTube channel and i open YouTube to post my videos.That is when i get distracted. Anyway it's still usefull when watching videos...

Comment: Is there any way we can hide these in YouTube app itself?

Comment: @AbhinavPB unlikely, since it's YouTube's own app and we can only use what settings that Google provides.